# Cannot get subl command working for ST3 on OSX

Tags: macos, git, sublimetext3

I am trying to get the Subl command working on my Mac OSX Mavericks. I have ST3 in my root applications folder.

When I run the line below, I also run it with sudo and get the same message.

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
```

In the terminal I get the following error

```
ln: /Users/username/bin/subl: No such file or directory
```

I double checked to see if it was working or not with

```
subl --help
```

but get the following error

```
-bash: subl: command not found
```

I am trying to get this to work so I can use it with Git and open file with sublime from there https://help.github.com/articles/associating-text-editors-with-git#using-sublime-text-as-your-editor

My .bash_profile looks like the following

```
export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
export EDITOR='subl -w'

if [ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ]; then
    source ~/.git-completion.bash
fi
```

Can anyone advise how to fix this problem,
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the issue is that you don't have a `/Users/username/bin` directory in the first place, so your `ln` command trying to create a symlink isn't working. Secondary to that, even if `~/bin` *did* exist, it's not part of your `PATH`, so the `subl` command won't ever be found.

To make things much easier for you, just create the symlink in `/usr/local/bin`. It (hopefully) already exists, and is already in your `PATH`. Just run

```
sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl
```

and you should be all set.

---

In response to your comment: There are 2 commands here - `ln`, which creates a [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link), and `export`, which just creates an [environment variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) (`PATH` is a special environment variable that contains the list of directories searched for commands when you enter something in Terminal).

When you create a symlink, the entire directory tree needs to exist before the link will be created. So, while `/Users` and `/Users/username` already existed, `/Users/username/bin` did not, so the `ln` command failed, regardless of whether `sudo` was used. In order to create the `bin` directory in your home directory (also known as `~`), you would first have needed to run `mkdir ~/bin`, then create the symlink with your first `ln` command (the one without the `sudo`). Next, you would have needed to add `~/bin` to your `PATH` environment variable by replacing the first two lines in `~/.bash_profile` with

```
export PATH=~/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH
```

However, since `/usr/local/bin` was already in your `PATH`, the easiest solution was to create the symlink to `subl` there, instead of creating a new `~/bin` directory, making the symlink, editing `~/.bash_profile`, then restarting your shell.

Comment: Thanks this works, but unfortunately i dont understand why. From tutorials i thought my second export statement created the directory i needed

Comment: @PierceMcGeough please see my expanded answer above, hopefully that explains why I did what I did, and why your original attempts failed.

Comment: thanks that make a lot of sense. A few different tutorials said the ~/bin should already be there. If I remove the line export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH" should it stop working?

Answer (score 0):

I also have this requirement. I use `alias` instead of those symbolic link method. It is rather easy and here is how.

Step1: Open ~/.bash_profile, add below line into it then save and close it.

```
alias subl='/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl'
```

Step2: execute `source` to make the `alias` setting take effect.

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Now you can use command `subl` following by a file or directory path to open them, enjoy!